# Get HTML source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using the Python bindings to run Selenium WebDriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I know I can grab a webelement like so:

```
elem = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('#my-id')
```

And I know I can get the full page source with...

```
wd.page_source
```

But is there a way to get the "element source"?

```
elem.source   # <-- returns the HTML as a string
```

The Selenium WebDriver documentation for Python are basically non-existent and I don't see anything in the code that seems to enable that functionality.

What is the best way to access the HTML of an element (and its children)?

Comment: You also could just parse all the `wd.page_source` with beautifulsoup

Comment: selenium has more facilities compare to beautiful soup.

Answer (score 1015, accepted):

You can read the `innerHTML` attribute to get the source of the *content* of the element or `outerHTML` for the source with the current element.

Python:

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Java:

```
elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

C#:

```
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Ruby:

```
element.attribute("innerHTML")
```

JavaScript:

```
element.getAttribute('innerHTML');
```

PHP:

```
$element->getAttribute('innerHTML');
```

It was tested and worked with the `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: innerHTML is a not DOM attribute. So above answer wouldn't work. innerHTML is a javascript javascript value. Doing above would return null. The answer by nilesh is the proper answer.

Comment: This works great for me, and is much more elegant than the accepted answer.  I'm using Selenium 2.24.1.

Comment: Though innerHTML is not a DOM attribute, it is well supported by all major browsers (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html). It works also well for me.

Comment: +1 This appears to work in ruby also. I have a feeling that the `getAttribute` method (or equivalent in other languages) just calls the js method whose name is the arg. However the documentation doesn't explicitly say this, so nilesh's solution should be a fallback.

Comment: I'm getting this: content.get_attribute('innerHTML') ==
u'<div>...</div>'

Comment: **This fails for `HtmlUnitDriver`.** Works for `ChromeDriver`, `FirefoxDriver`, `InternetExplorerDriver` (IE10) and `PhantomJSDriver` (I haven't tested others).

Comment: @acdcjunior - HtmlUnit's javascript support is pretty weak; I'd imagine by extension they haven't supported this. More info [at this thread](http://htmlunit.10904.n7.nabble.com/How-to-get-inner-HTML-of-an-html-element-td25936.html)

Comment: In Ruby it `element.attribute("innerHTML")` if anyone needs it.

Comment: nice- 

elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") 

It works by using this.

Comment: in Node:
`element.getAttribute('innerHTML')`

Comment: I have a situation where an alert text is displayed and I want to catch. Neither `driver.page_source` nor `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` can return contents containing that alert text. In Firefox,only "`inspect elements |right click <HTML>|copy|inner HTML`" give me what I need. How can I mimic that action chain in Selenium Python?

Answer (score 104):

There is not really a straightforward way of getting the HTML source code of a `webelement`. You will have to use JavaScript. I am not too sure about python bindings, but you can easily do like this in Java. I am sure there must be something similar to `JavascriptExecutor` class in Python.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
 String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing, albeit with the Python equivalent.

Comment: I think the answer below, using element.getAttribute("innerHTML") is a lot easier to read.  I don't understand why people are voting it down.

Comment: No need to call javascript at all. In Python just use element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: @Anthon `innerHTML`is not a DOM attribute. When I answered this question in 2011, it did not work for me, looks like now some browsers are supporting it. If it works for you then using `innerHTML` is cleaner. However there is no guarantee it will work on all browsers.

Comment: Apparently, this is the only way to get innerHTML while using RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 100):

Here's how to get the HTML source code using Selenium Python:

```py
elem = driver.find_element("xpath", "//*")
source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

Here's how to save that HTML to a file:

```py
with open('c:/html_source_code.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Can I set a delay and get the latest source? There are dynamic contents loaded using javascript.

Comment: Does this work even if the page is not fully loaded? Also, is there any way to set a delay like @FlyingAtom mentioned?

Comment: If Webpage contain dynamic contents then it depends upon behavior of that webpage but 90%, you had to set delay before getting raw HTML from that page. And most simplest way is ```time.sleep(x) # Where x is seconds``` to set delay.

Comment: This is an old answer. Nowadays, the method `find_element_by_xpath` no longer exists, and this gives `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'`. So, now, instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")`, you should use `driver .find_element("xpath", "//*")`. Found that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754667/540552).

Answer (score 15):

In Ruby, using selenium-webdriver (2.32.1), there is a `page_source` method that contains the entire page source.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers provide a lot of details about retrieving the markup of a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139). However, an important aspect is, modern websites are increasingly implementing [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/), [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html), etc. to render the dynamic elements within the [DOM tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). Hence there is a necessity to wait for the element and its children to completely render before retrieving the markup.

---

### Python

Hence, ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `get_attribute("outerHTML")`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#my-id")))
  print(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `execute_script()`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#my-id")))
  print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].outerHTML;", element))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: An essential question is, what kind of HTML I get: 1) just the source tunneled through selenium or b) the source after chrome (depending on the driver also Safari or Firefox) rendered it?

Answer (score 7):

It looks outdated, but let it be here anyway. The correct way to do it in your case:

```
elem = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('#my-id')
html = wd.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", elem)
```

or

```
html = elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Both are working for me (selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0).

Answer (score 6):

Using the attribute method is, in fact, easier and more straightforward.

Using Ruby with the Selenium and PageObject gems, to get the class associated with a certain element, the line would be `element.attribute(Class)`.

The same concept applies if you wanted to get other attributes tied to the element. For example, if I wanted the *string* of an element, `element.attribute(String)`.

Answer (score 4):

Java with Selenium 2.53.0

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Comment: that's not what the question asked for

Comment: Depending on the webdriver, the `getPageSource` method may not return the actual page source (ie with possible javascript changements). The returned source may be the raw source sent by the server. The webdriver doc must be checked to ensure this point.

Comment: Also works for php - `$driver->getPageSource()`

Answer (score 4):

InnerHTML will return the element inside the selected element and outerHTML will return the inside HTML along with the element you have selected

Example:

Now suppose your Element is as below

```
<tr id="myRow"><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
```

#### innerHTML element output

```
<td>A</td><td>B</td>
```

#### outerHTML element output

```
<tr id="myRow"><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
```

Live Example:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/JavascriptDemo/f/find_out_the_difference_between_innerhtml_and_outerhtml_in_javascript_example.htm

Below you will find the syntax which require as per different binding. Change the `innerHTML` to `outerHTML` as per required.

Python:

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Java:

```
elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

If you want whole page HTML, use the below code:

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Answer (score 3):

## Updated 2022 Selenium Retrieving HTML

To start with, download the Python bindings for Selenium WebDriver.

- One can do this from the PyPI page for the Selenium package.
- Alternatively, one can use pip to install the Selenium package. Python 3.6 provides the pip in the standard library.

### Method 1

Read the `innerHTML` attribute to get the source of the element’s content. `innerHTML` is a property of a DOM element whose value is the HTML between the opening tag and ending tag.

For example, the innerHTML property in the code below carries the value “text”

```html
<p>
a text
</p>
```

```py
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

### Method 2

Read the `outerHTML` to get the source with the current element. `outerHTML` is an element property whose value is the HTML between the opening and closing tags and the HTML of the selected element itself.

For example, the code’s `outerHTML` property carries a value that contains `div` and `span` inside that.

```html
<div>
<span>Hello there!</span>
</div>
```

```py
ele.get_atrribute("outerHTML")
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this could help:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

Here is described Java method:

```
java.lang.String    getText()
```

But unfortunately it's not available in Python. So you can translate the method names to Python from Java and try another logic using present methods without getting the whole page source...

E.g.

```
 my_id = elem[0].get_attribute('my-id')
```

Comment: Python actually does have a "gettext" equivalent (I think its just the "text" attribute?) but that actually just returns the "plaintext" between HTML tags and won't actually return the full HTML source.

Comment: This returns only the plain text (not the html) in Java too.

Comment: you must reference it like you said elem[0] otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The method to get the rendered HTML I prefer is the following:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
body_html = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
print body_html.text
```

However, the above method removes all the tags (yes, the nested tags as well) and returns only text content. If you interested in getting the HTML markup as well, then use the method below.

```
print body_html.getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: You can also use driver.find_element_by_tag("body") to reach the body content of the page.

Comment: This works in Excel VBA with Selenium but needs some adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

This works seamlessly for me.

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a solution for [Selenium Remote Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_Remote_Control) in Python, here is how to get innerHTML:

```
innerHTML = sel.get_eval("window.document.getElementById('prodid').innerHTML")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have used this. I also find `innerHTML = {solenium selector code}.text` works just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use execute_script get html

bs4(BeautifulSoup) also can access html tag quickly.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = adriver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
bs4_onepage_object=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
bs4_div_object=bs4_onepage_object.find_all("atag",class_="attribute")
```

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of **php-webdriver** (1.12.0+) you have to use

```
$element->getDomProperty('innerHTML');
```

as pointed out in this issue: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/issues/929

Comment: Why an answer using PHP when the question is specifically about Python?

Comment: @Laurent I answered you above. The reason is that for similar requests for PHP, Google issues this page

Answer (score 0):

In [PHP Selenium WebDriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) you can get page source like this:

```php
$html = $driver->getPageSource();
```

Or get HTML of the element like this:

```php
// innerHTML if you need HTML of the element content
$html = $element->getDomProperty('outerHTML');
```

Comment: Question is about Python not PHP

Comment: @Laurent I know i can read but google search for php returns this page

Comment: @Laurent this answer has upvotes, which means it was helpful to someone

Answer (score -1):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

This code really works to get JavaScript from source as well!

Answer (score -1):

And in [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) Selenium test it's like this:

```
$text = $this->byCssSelector('.some-class-nmae')->attribute('innerHTML');
```

Comment: Question is about Python not PHP