# Selenium pattern matching

Tags: selenium

Needed some help with pattern matching in Selenium. I am trying to read the following inner div tags,

```
<div>
     <div class="xyz one"></div>

     <div class="xyz two"></div>

     <div class="xyz three"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can do this? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an XPath that you can use in order to select all div tags that contain the text 'xyz'.

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'xyz')]"
```

So in order to use this, you'd use this line, which creates a collection of all the divs with the text 'xyz'

```
var divElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'xyz')]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.xyz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question has already been answered 
[Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python)
Then you can parse your output.

*EDIT*

To make things easier: (Using Python)

Try:

```
class_list = [] 
my_divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(div[class*=xyz])
for div in my_divs:
   outerHTML = div.get_attribute("outerHTML")
   classpos = outerHTML.find('class=') #find where our class identifier begins
   quote_begin = outerHTML.find('"',classpos) 
   quote_end = outerHTML.find('"', quote_begin+1)
   our_class = outerHTML[classpos:quote_end+1] #get the entire class identifier
   class_list.append(our_class)
   print our_class
```

I'm sure theres someone with a one liner of code that does the same thing that my 4 lines does but this was what I could come up with. Also, this code can be changed around pretty quickly into Java