# is it technically possible to validate resizing through selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, resize

I'm trying to automate a test case that covers resizing a div element and making sure everything stays the same in the div (except the size of it of course). Is there a way to do this through Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, so here are 3 things you can verify:

Look at the HTML when you are resizing.  If, say an element gains a class "small", then you can do something like `element.getAttribute("class").contains("small");`

If the CSS changes, then you can do `element.getCSSValue("someAttribute").contains("something")`

Finally, if you want to make sure that none of the HTML changes at all, then you need to get the source of the WebElement, which requires a work around (described here: [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python) )