# How to ignore children classes when extracting text from a class using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am trying to extract the text from a class on html page using Selenium in Python. While doing so, my code is also extracting the text from its child class.

Below is the code I am using:

```
monthlyprice = browser.find_element_by_class_name('tila-container').text
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="tila-container tila-term header7a">
+ $8
<sup class="super-decimal-price">25</sup>
x 24/mo. If you cancel wireless service, remaining balance on phone becomes due. 0% APR O.A.C for well-qualified buyers. Qual’g service req’d.
</div>
```

Above pasted piece of HTML code is the one which is causing problem, I want to extract text value **+ $8** mentioned under **tila-container** class but my code is giving me text present under its child class **super-decimal-price** and I also don't want text mentioned after this child class starting from "x 24/mo."

Folks help me in resolving this.

Comment: Instead of a link, it's more useful if you can paste in a copy of the html which is causing a problem. What are the class and subclass you're referring to?

Comment: @vincebowdren I have made the edit according to requirements.

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks. I think you're using the terms *class* and *subclass* incorrectly; the relationship between the `div` and `sup` in the DOM hierarchy is not class-subclass but parent-child. So what you're asking for is a way to get the text content of the div, but not including the text content of the div's children.

Comment: @vincebowdren Ohh, okay. I didn't know about that, I have made the changes in question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult. As far as webdriver is concerned, the text before and after the child `<span>` is equally validly part of the text content; and it doesn't have methods to just return bits and pieces of the text content.

What I'd try is:

1. Use a method to get the full inner html of the div.
2. Use string manipulation to divide it up into three parts; before the `<span>`, the `<span>` itself, and after the `<span>`.

The first part is reasonably straightforward; see [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python) for how to get the html source of a single element.

The second part is not too difficult either; it should be easy enough with python's string functions. It will get complicated, however, if the format of the inner text is more variable (i.e. not just text-span-text each time).

Good luck!