# How do I get the HTML Source of the node h2 with the WebElement in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, html

I have a website that has such a piece of source:

```
<div class="wrapper group">
 <h2>
    <span>
    1.
    </span>
    Créez votre site.
 </h2>
</div>
```

I want to get this string

```
"<span>1.</span>Créez votre site."
```

to do some verification. How do I get such a string?

By the way, there is an existing piece of code in the java project to get the text:

```
public static final SeBlob STEP_ONE = new SeBlob("div.wrapper.group>h2");

 driver.findElement(WebsitesElements.STEP_ONE.getBy()).getText();
```

The result is "1. Créez votre site", which is not what I want.

Comment: Two things: the way you describe it, you want the HTML of the entire `h2` tag, not the `span` tag as said in your title. Otherwise you'd be getting simply "1.", as opposed to the rest of it. Secondly, in what programming language is this?

Comment: Hi Arran, thank you very much! I have changed my description according to your suggestion.

Comment: Then in which case, this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python ...also the question is about Python, the accepted answer is Java.

Comment: Yes, according to your link, I can get the string using "driver.findElement(WebsitesElements.STEP_ONE.getBy()).getAttribute("innerHTML").trim();". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Arran's comments, I solved the problem with the following statement:
"driver.findElement(WebsitesElements.STEP_ONE.getBy()).getAttribute("innerHTML")‌​.trim();".

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the WebElement, then execute the Javascript command that retrieves the innerHTML

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(WebsitesElements.STEP_ONE.getBy());

String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```