# Selenium Webdriver with Python - obtaining the string or contents in between html tags

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium's webdriver and Python. [I know about this article about getting the HTML source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python), but I don't want the entire HTML line for a DOM object, just the content in between the tags. [I also looked at webdriver source code for help on finding this button DOM object](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py)

for example:

```
<button id = "picview">Pic View</button>
```

How do I just get "Pic View"?

Also, using get_attribute("button id"), How would I get this specific button id as there are multiple buttons on the page with button id?

For example:

```
picbox_elem_attr = picbox_elem.get_attribute('button id')
print picbox_elem_attr
```

How do I ensure that picbox_elem_attr variable is set to the "picview" button and not some other button?

I don't have a

```
driver.find_element_by_name("xxx")
```

or a

```
driver.find_element_by_id("aaa")
```

to use to find this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get text of an element use the text property. For example:

```
text_inside_button_id = driver.find_element_by_id("picview").text
```

Here is some additional documentation to help you with the webdriver binding library.
http://goldb.org/sst/selenium2_api_docs/html/

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through the api doc, but don't know where to find this type of functionality. I know the high level find functions from looking at the source code, but your doc might be easier if I knew where to look.

Comment: Look under  selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement: WebElement implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about xpath. Oops!

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picview"]')
```

and then you can right-click the object and use xpath within the dev tools.