# Not Able to get data from a HTML dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a web application with web driver
I have this dynamic table generated when I enter a keyword and click search button:

```
<div id="mainView">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="search_results_table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <td>
    <a href="#/en/object?company=WAR001&area=X&mu=BIST_CE466&name=TSK(BEN721JUU5)(000)">
    <b class="ng-binding">TSK(BEN721JUU5)(000)</b>
    </a>
    <p style="font-size:11px">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do is loop through the table and extract the value between   tags.
In the code above the value I would like to extract is : `TSK(BEN721JUU5)(000)`

I have written the following code so far, but I don't know why this is not printing anything.

```
@Test
private void srch() throws MalformedURLException, IOException  {
    driver.get(TestURL);
    WebElement input1 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_user_input"));
    input1.sendKeys("guest");
    WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_password_input"));
    input2.sendKeys("guest");
    WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.id("login_form_signin_button"));
    btn.click();
    WebElement w1 = driver.findElement(By.id("header_search_text_field"));
    w1.sendKeys("tsk");
    WebElement resulttable = driver.findElement(By.id("search_results_table"));
    List<WebElement> rows = resulttable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
    for (WebElement row : rows) { 
            List<WebElement> cols = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
            System.out.println(cols.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
                    WebElement data = cols.get(i);
                    System.out.println(data.getText());
            }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `document.innerHTML` tag from JavaScript?

something like this,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

I found the answer on [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python)