# Getting the HTML code of a particular div using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium in Python, I'd like to download a page, and save the HTML code of a particular div, identified by its *id*. I've got the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
   browser.get(current_url)

WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=3).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('element_id'))

element = browser.find_element_by_id('element_id')
```

`element` is of type `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`. Is there a way to get the HTML code (not processed in any way) from `element`? Is there some better way, using Selenium, of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Does it have to be selenium?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution specifically using selenium. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from `pydoc selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement`:

```
 |  text
 |      Gets the text of the element.
```

Use the `.text` attribute.

If you really are after the HTML source of the element
then please see: [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-python)

As stated above, it's not as straight forward as you'd like.

Comment: The text attribute produces the visible text (i.e. what one sees when viewing a page) rather than the HTML code.

Comment: A variant of this reply from the thread you linked above took care of it: elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*"); source_code = elem.get_attribute("innerHTML"). Thanks!