# Is there a way to get the HTML of an element?

Tags: selenium, fluentautomation

I'm using the FluentAutomation version of Selenium, and I can't find any way to get the HTML of an element.  I can get the text and attributes, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get the full HTML content, which I need for a certain kind of test I'm doing.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or the [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML), you should just be able to call `GetAttribute` on the element, or whatever it is in your language.

Example C#:

```
element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Example Ruby:

```
element.attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: That totally worked, thanks!  In VB.NET, the syntax is: `I.Find("html").Invoke().Attributes.Get("outerHTML")`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if a straight-forward way exists, anyway, it should be possible to execute something similar to:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Comment: make it complete like this
http://www.seleniumstutorial.com/getting-innerhtml-element-using-remotewebdriver/