# Inspection in Youtube Playback Window

Tags: inspection

I'm a beginner for selenium.
I want to know how to inspect the quality of a video like(144p,240p,720p..) in settings button in youtube playback.

Comment: This question has already been answered on stackoverflow, please check the following :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306566/how-to-get-inspect-element-code-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Inspect Element code in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306566/how-to-get-inspect-element-code-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press f12 and right click on the element you want to select, select copy xpath. Following is the xpath for the settings option and child it has respectively

```
//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[25]/div[2]/div[2]/button[3]
 document.querySelector("#ytp-id-21")
```

Comment: After Pressing F12 and then i right clicked on setting button in youtube window but i'm not able to inspect and it is giving option as loop,copy video URL,etc.can u please help me?

Comment: Do right click on the element, select inspect(this is for mac)

Comment: Then how to inspect on normal laptop