# Can't capture by driver.find_element_by_xpath used by selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

I am trying to capture a button to click on it. the source url is:

```
The goal is to provide free information to website users and owners regarding website security status.
                <br>
                <br>
                Use it wisely or we'll have to take it away.
            </p>
        </div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Accept</span></button></div></div></div></body></html>
```

What I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
url='http://example.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.page_source
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"]/span[@class="ui-button-text"]/text()').click()
driver.quit()
```

The Error Message is:

```
File "u.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="button"]/span[@class="ui-button-text"]/text()').click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 230, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'Error Message => \'The result of the xpath expression "//button[@type="button"]/span[@class="ui-button-text"]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.\'\n caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"149","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:57776","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\\"using\\": \\"xpath\\", \\"sessionId\\": \\"7b17cc00-6500-11e4-9c4e-e1b4bf9ba927\\", \\"value\\": \\"//button[@type=\\\\\\"button\\\\\\"]/span[@class=\\\\\\"ui-button-text\\\\\\"]/text()\\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7b17cc00-6500-11e4-9c4e-e1b4bf9ba927/element"}' ; Screenshot: available via screen
```

## UPDATE:

When I use it in the following way it works:

```
from lxml import html
cont="""<br>
                    <br>
                    Use it wisely or we'll have to take it away.
                </p>
            </div><div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix"><div class="ui-dialog-buttonset"><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-focus" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Accept</span></button></div></div></div></body></html>
"""

tree=html.fromstring(cont)
print tree.xpath('//button[@type="button"]/span[@class="ui-button-text"]/text()')
```

returns:

```
['Accept']
```

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know. Removed the `/text()` from the XPath expression.

Comment: But without usig selenium I tested that xpath structure and returned  me `Accept`

Comment: Yes, the text not the element. Text is not clickable. You need the surrounding element for that.

Comment: please see the update part

Comment: Yes, of course it returns the text. But you can't click a text node. You need to click the span which contains the text. Text cannot have a click handler. I don't know how I can make it clearer. Have you tried my suggestion from the first comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//button[@type="button"]/span[@class="ui-button-text"]').click()
```

without the `/text()` at the end of your XPath expression. What Artjom B. was explaining to you in the comments is that if you use `find_element_by_xpath`, the XPath expression you pass to this method **must resolve to an HTML element**. The XPath you were giving it is valid as far as *XPath* is concerned, yes. But the fact that it is a valid XPath expression is not enough. The value of the expression you have in your question is a *string*, not an element, but Selenium absolutely needs an element.

Comment: +1 Thank you... I want to get source of page after clicking on Accept, So what I should do now?

Comment: That's a completely different question from the one you originally asked here. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7263824/1906307) for ways to do it. If the methods there do not help, then post a new question and *make sure to explain why your question is not a duplicate of the one I gave a link to*. Otherwise, it is going to be closed as duplicate.