# How to get innerHTML of whole page in selenium driver?

Tags: selenium

I'm using `selenium` to click to the web page I want, and then parse the web page using `Beautiful Soup`.

Somebody has shown [how to get inner HTML of an element in a `Selenium WebDriver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python). Is there a way to get HTML of the whole page? Thanks

The sample code in `Python`
(Based on the post above, the language seems to not matter too much):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.google.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

the_html = driver---somehow----.get_attribute('innerHTML')
bs = BeautifulSoup(the_html, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To get the HTML for the whole page:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

html = driver.page_source
```

To get the outer HTML (tag included):

```py
# HTML from `<html>`
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;")

# HTML from `<body>`
html = driver.execute_script("return document.body.outerHTML;")

# HTML from element with some JavaScript
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#hireme")
html = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].outerHTML;", element)

# HTML from element with `get_attribute`
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#hireme")
html = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

To get the inner HTML (tag excluded):

```py
# HTML from `<html>`
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")

# HTML from `<body>`
html = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")

# HTML from element with some JavaScript
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#hireme")
html = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element)

# HTML from element with `get_attribute`
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#hireme")
html = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: thanks @florentbr.  there seems to be a simpler answer for an element in the post mentioned in OP, `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` ---- does your answer to the same thing, or which one is more powerful/flexible?

Answer (score 2):

`driver.page_source` probably outdated. Following worked for me

```
let html = await driver.getPageSource();
```

Reference: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/ie_exports_Driver.html#getPageSource

Comment: For posterity, a short clarification that the answer above by @Florent B. is referring to the Python API, whereas this one is the JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: How do you do this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Using page object in Java:

```java
    @FindBy(xpath = "xapth")
    private WebElement element;

    public String getInnnerHtml() {
        System.out.println(waitUntilElementToBeClickable(element, 10).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
        return waitUntilElementToBeClickable(element, 10).getAttribute("innerHTML")
    }
```

Comment: What is the benefit of going this way to click an element ?

Answer (score 0):

A C# snippet for those of us who might want to copy / paste a bit of working code some day

```cs
var element = yourWebDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));
string outerHTML = element.GetAttribute(nameof(outerHTML));
```

Thanks to those who answered before me. Anyone in the future who benefits from this snippet of C# that gets the HTML for any page element in a Selenium test, please consider up voting this answer or leaving a comment.