# Use an already open webpage(with selenium) to beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have a web page open and logged in using webdriver code. Using webdriver for this because the page requires login and various other actions before I am set to scrape.

The aim is to scrape data from this open page. Need to find links and open them, so there will be a lot of combination between selenium webdriver and BeautifulSoup.

I looked at the documentation for bs4 and the `BeautifulSoup(open("ccc.html"))` throws an error

`soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open("https://m/search.mp?ss=Pr+Dn+Ts"))`

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://m/search.mp?ss=Pr+Dn+Ts'

I assume this is because its not a `.html`?

Comment: see [how to get innerHTML of whole page in selenium driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905517/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-whole-page-in-selenium-driver)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to open a page by a web address. `open()` would not do that, use `urlopen()`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # Python 3
# from urllib2 import urlopen  # Python 2

url = "your target url here"
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
```

Or, use an HTTP for humans - [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

Also note that it is strongly advisable to [*specify a parser explicitly*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) - I've used `html.parser` in this case, there are other parsers available.

---

> I want to use the exact same page(same instance)

A common way to do it is to get the [`driver.page_source`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) and pass it to `BeautifulSoup` for further parsing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# wait for page to load..

source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()  # remove this line to leave the browser open

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain properly, the page is already open. :( I want to use the exact same page(same instance) opened by selenium. In both the examples I assume a new url based request is being made to the open/get the data.

Comment: @Sid alright, I've updated the answer - please see if this is what you've meant. Thanks.

Comment: The third one was exactly what I was looking for. :) Thanks