# Python Automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to capture a test case result where table content Search/filter output need to cross check each time when the test run. I have attached a table grid that I need to use to search/filter.  I'm using python script for the automation.

Any suggestion?

[image: Table grid with multiple rows and columns]

Answer (score 3):

You can use selenium to test. The table's inner HTML can be accessed using 
`table_content = element.get_attribute('innerHTML').`

 you can parse that HTML to cross check your results.
Have a look at this question for reference.

[Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)