# How can I get HTML code of a WebElement or an attribute of a WebElement?

Tags: python, selenium, jpeg, src

What I get so far:

```
 def picture(self):
    path = "/home/user/Desktop/cat.jpg"
    path2 = "/home/user/Desktop/puppy.jpg"
    pictureName  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingAvatar"]')
    self.captureScreen('picture', 1)
    editPhoto.send_keys(path)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(pictureName)
    self.captureScreen('picture', 2)
    editPhoto.send_keys(path2)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(pictureName)
```

So basically, when I select CSS or Xpath of the element which contains src, it prints completely different information like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="bba710d8-ac5e-4e96-b946-14b3eda53cca", element="6d243513-8109-495e-a7a4-e4d218bbbd9a")>
```

Comment: Of course `driver.find_element_by_xpath` returns a `WebElement` object. What kind of result were you expecting? Unparsed HTML source?

Comment: I am expecting to see this: <img id="easSettingAvatar" src="https://eas.eightdevelopment.net/getAvatar/c453a847-060a-441d-8395-1d71f697e90d.jpg"> or just src

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code to: pictureName  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingAvatar"]')
        source_code = pictureName.get_attribute("outerHTML")  and the outcome I got is now: <img id="easSettingAvatar" src="https://eas.eightdevelopment.net/getAvatar/fda57c35-9ed6-4c22-ba55-160b4ed9b480.jpg">
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="5ee634e5-f284-43ab-b26a-cc9ea0ad35ff", element="29f027b8-d63d-4ca1-801b-7b909c2abcc8")>

Comment: Any ideas how to get rid of the last part, which is "<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="5ee634e5-f284-43ab-b26a-cc9ea0ad35ff", element="29f027b8-d63d-4ca1-801b-7b909c2abcc8")>
"?

Comment: Well, you have _two_ `print`s in your code... Have you updated both of them? Maybe remove the second one?

Comment: thanks, it was a mess. all fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You have to print attribute of the WebElement instead of print the WebElement.

```
def picture(self):
    path = "/home/user/Desktop/cat.jpg"
    path2 = "/home/user/Desktop/puppy.jpg"
    pictureName  = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easSettingAvatar"]')
    self.captureScreen('picture', 1)
    editPhoto.send_keys(path)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(pictureName.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    print(pictureName.get_attribute('src'))
    self.captureScreen('picture', 2)
    editPhoto.send_keys(path2)
    time.sleep(5)
```

The result should be

```
<img id="easSettingAvatar" src="eas.eightdevelopment.net/getAvatar/…; 
eas.eightdevelopment.net/getAvatar/…
```