# Get the source code of an element

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver, laravel-5, webdriver, laravel-dusk

Is there a similar way in Laravel Dusk as we have in Selenium, to get the source code of an element by '**innerHTML attribute**'?

Ex: innerHTML for `<div>Hello <p>World!</p></div>` would be:
`Hello <p>World!</p>`.

Comment: Didn't this help ? [get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

Comment: I am looking for a Dusk solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get source code of element you should use `element()` method together with `getAttribute` like this:

```
$this->browse(function(Browser $browser) {

    $html = $browser->visit('/')
                    ->element('div.content')
                    ->getAttribute('innerHTML');

   // now in $html you have HTML inside div.content element
});
```

Be aware in case you have multiple elements with given selector you should use `elements()` method and iterate over found elements to get their content like this:

```
$this->browse(function(Browser $browser) {
    $elements = $browser->visit('/')
                        ->elements('div.content');

    $html = [];
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $html[] = $element->getAttribute('innerHTML');
    }

    // now in $html you have array of HTML inside div.content elements
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to the right Dusk documentation with all available commands / methods. Are 'element' and 'getAttribute' Dusk methods or PHP Selenium commands?

Comment: You can look at `vendor/laravel/dusk/Concerns` files. In `InteractsWithElements` you will find elements and element methods. But `getAttribute` method is from FaebookWebDriver - this is located in `Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement` class

Comment: Thanks, I found them under  `vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/InteractsWithElements.php` and `vendor/Facebook/WebDriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebElement.php`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Selenium `innerHTML` but with Dusk you can assert directly against the source code via `$browser->assertSourceHas($code)`.

You'll get to see the full source code of your site if the assertion fails.

```
public function testSourceCode()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->assertSourceHas('Hello <p>World!</p>');
        });
    }
```

Comment: By assertSourceHas, you already know the source code, but by innerHTML you get the value of an unknown source code.