# How to select <thead> then <tbody> when scraping data from web page

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

[image][image]I have been learning about scraping data from web pages using Excel and VBA. I cam across a bit of a barrier with one data source so changed to https://www.skyscanner.net/news/airports/heathrow-airport-live-flight-arrivals-and-departures.
The problem I am coming up against is in the table id "flight-status-board-arrivals" there is a  and .
I can pull the header data fine but when I try bulling the body data the loop ends. I have tried changing to .children(1) to test and debugging using length which returns 0. This indicates there is nothing in the object but I cant understand why. I hope I have covered everything here and any help would be possible. Also, I know this could be achieved using another language however as I am learning VBA I thought it best to learn using VBa before delving into a new language.`

```
Sub GrabWebData()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer 'refer to the running copy of internet explorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument 'refer to the HTML document returned
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim fSht As Worksheet

Set fSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "https://www.skyscanner.net/news/airports/heathrow-airport-live-flight-arrivals-and-departures"

'wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Loading Flight Times"
DoEvents
Loop

y = 1

Debug.Print ie.document.getElementById("flight-status-board-arrivals").Children(1) _
.getElementsByTagName("td").Length


For Each ele In ie.document.getElementById("flight-status-board- arrivals").Children(1) _
.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Debug.Print ele.textContent
fSht.Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
'On Error GoTo skip1:
fSht.Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
'On Error GoTo skip1:
fSht.Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
'On Error GoTo skip1:
fSht.Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
'On Error GoTo skip1:
fSht.Range("E" & y).Value = ele.Children(4).textContent
'On Error GoTo skip1:
fSht.Cells.WrapText = False
fSht.Rows.AutoFit
fSht.Columns.AutoFit
'skip1:
y = y + 1
Next

'Rows(2).Select
'Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp

End Sub`
```

Comment: You are not getting anything except for the headers just because the data within `tbody` load very late or never load in IE. I waited for 5 minutes to see what happens, but could not find the data getting loaded. In such cases `selenium` might be a good way to go with.

Comment: @SIM thanks for that, I will check it out. I was thinking that the reason it doesn't load is because the data on the site in tbody is updating regularly but I thought there should still be data there to load. Could that be the case?

Comment: If you can't see any visible text out there (within tbody) using IE, how can the script fetch that? However, I will check it out too!!

Comment: @SIM do you mean on the actual page using IE? If so the text/data shows on the page. If you check the “td”  in tbody and watch the “tr” I think it is, these seem to scramble on the refresh. That’s why I thought it could be the issue. Look forward to hear your findings

Comment: Check out [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4jyxfbgemntu3j/Untitled.jpg?dl=0) to understand what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to get the data from that table. I've defined `Explicit Wait` within the script so that it will wait until the tabular data has been available in that webpage. Although I would strongly suggest you to follow the way `QHarr` has already shown, you can give this a shot additionally. The script will run headlessly so you won't see any browser. However, the only problem is that you may encounter a `stale element` error somewhere within the operation, not always though.

This is how the script looks like:

```
Sub FetchData()
    Const link As String = "https://www.skyscanner.net/news/airports/heathrow-airport-live-flight-arrivals-and-departures"
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, elem As Object, R&, C&

    With New ChromeDriver
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .get link
        Set posts = .FindElementByCss("#flight-status-board-arrivals tbody tr", Timeout:=30000)
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss("#flight-status-board-arrivals tr")
            For Each elem In post.FindElementsByCss("th,td")
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = elem.Text
            Next elem
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

To make the execution time a lot faster and revert back to `HTMLDocument` parser reusing the `.PageSource`, you should try like below.

```
Sub FetchData()
    Const link As String = "https://www.skyscanner.net/news/airports/heathrow-airport-live-flight-arrivals-and-departures"
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, elem As Object, R&, C&
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument

    With New ChromeDriver
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .get link
        Set posts = .FindElementByCss("#flight-status-board-arrivals tbody tr", timeout:=30000)
        Html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource  'this is how you can go
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementById("flight-status-board-arrivals").Rows
        For Each elem In post.Cells
            C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = elem.innerText
        Next elem
        C = 0: R = R + 1
    Next post
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library before execution:

```
Selenium Type Library
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: thanks for this. I just tried to run this but it still returned n automation error. I included the Selenium library and have the chromedriver installed. I stepped through using F8 and it got to with new chromedriver and returned the error. I am using excel 2010 if that any help or has any bearing on the issue.

Comment: Can you run any script with the version of selenium you have installed, I meant have you checked any url to play with?

Comment: I encountered the same issue for the first time. However, the easy fix is to find any latest version of  `chromedriver.exe`, then download it and replace it with the one currently available in your installation folder (program files > selenium basic).

Comment: Check out the edit. I've kicked out the hardcoded delay and applied `Explicit Wait` in place.

Comment: Still having issues with the new chrome line. Will have a look and see what I can sort out and try the code

Comment: I have tried installing the ChromeDriver again and still experiencing the runtime error of automation error. I have included in the original post the references I have included in excel. Any ideas of where to go next?

Comment: Did you try replacing `chromedriver.exe` which is meant to be downloaded from another source.

Comment: S I have installed Selenium Basic and then installed the ChromeDriver but unable to find the file path so I can replace the .exe file. Checked in application data where a lot of posts advise to go but there is nothing there apart from a windows folder. Odd. I also installed the IDE hoping that might make a difference but it hasn't.

Comment: Found the folder and replaced file but still getting the error. Starting the run out of ideas

Comment: I tried few of that `exes` to get the chromedriver run successfully.

Comment: Try this. If it is possible for you to download. I'm using this now. [Download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u632niniwh6sfd2/chromedriver.exe?dl=0)

Comment: Added the driver you provided to the folder and once again returned the error (which I have now added to the original post)

Comment: I have managed to get this to work. .net framework had not been installed. Just tested by opening and closing a chrome browser window and worked a dream. Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: Html.body.innerHTML = .PageSource   +1 nice Didn't know about the headless bit either though makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you started. It is uses [selenium basic](http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/). After installing, you need to add a reference to selenium type library and HTML Object library.

Was in a hurry so I will come back and refine later.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, hTable As HTMLTable, html As HTMLDocument, doc As WebElement, headers(), b As Object
    headers = Array("Flight Details", "Status", "Scheduled Time", "Airline Flight", "Origin", "Terminal", "Status")
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.skyscanner.net/news/airports/heathrow-airport-live-flight-arrivals-and-departures"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get URL
        Set html = New HTMLDocument
        Set b = .FindElementById("flight-status-board-arrivals") '<== Only used to take advantage of implicit waits in Selenium. This is a TODO improve.
        html.body.innerHTML = .findElementByXPath("//body").Attribute("innerHTML")

        Set hTable = html.getElementById("flight-status-board-arrivals")

        WriteTable hTable, headers

        .Quit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, ByRef headers As Variant, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
        For Each tr In tRow
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each td In tCell                 'DispHTMLElementCollection
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                c = c + 1
            Next td
            r = r + 1:  c = 1
        Next tr
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Current sample snapshot of webpage:**

[image: Page]

---

**Current sample snapshot of code output:**

[image: Code output]

---

**Note:**

When inspecting the page additional info appears (front 2 columns before visible columns shown in screenshot above):

[image: Addit info]

Code captures all of these.

I was interested in seeing if I could transfer `innerHTML` from webElements, so as to use the properties of `.document`, or other HTML DOM objects. I found the way to do it in an answer by [@Nerijus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8575709/6241235).

Comment: It's a very nice piece of code. Genuinely awesome!!

Comment: Thanks. Needs a little tweaking. Maybe you can sort how one creates a new html table? I’d rather load the html into that than the entire document HTML. Was in a hurry so didn’t get a chance to look into it. If you solve please post as answer or whichever method you use!

Comment: The way you load the html is mindblowing. I just forgot to mention that. It's always a pleasure to learn new things.

Comment: @QHarr thanks for this. One thing though, after getting Selenium and chrome driver, I am struggling to get past the Set d = New ChromeDriver line. Any ideas? I will continue to search but any tips would be great.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error message of some sort? What is it? And is it on that line?

Comment: @SIM Seems I would have to do something like  document.createElement("TABLE")   to have HTMLTable so no real point trying for HTMLTable object. I could // to the id of the table though and load just that like I did with HTMLBody. Not sure it would be a massive improvement.....

Comment: @QHarr the error I get is an automation error on the line Set d = New ChromeDriver. I will install the newest versions of ChromeDriver and see if that works.

Comment: Yes. This can occur if you have an older version of chromedriver.

Comment: Check out my update answer @QHarr. It might be useful for future usage. Actually, I found it very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @SIM Will do! Thanks for letting me know.