# How to scroll down on Y-axis in HTML window?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape data from a SharePoint site that has a few windows.  Apparently, all data must be visible to be able to scrape it (JavaScript).  I'm trying to figure out how to scroll down in the window and scrape the data at the same time.  The window is identified as:

```
<div class="md-virtual-repeat-offsetter" role="presentation" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
```

As I scroll down in this window, the `translateY(0px)` increases as such:  32px, 64px, 96px, etc., up to 31250px.  How can I increase the number of pixels and scrape all HTML elements in this window?  I think the code should be something like this.

```
#first move to the element
wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);', scroll_size)
#then scroll by x, y values, in this case 10 pixels up
wd.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 10000);')
```

But, when I run that, nothing happens.

Comment: Which lib are you using?

Comment: I have no clue what you are doing but you may consider emulating PageDown-PageUp button?

Comment: Using Beautiful Soup and Selenium.  Everything works fine, except for this scrolling task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

Comment: It seems _incredibly_ unlikely that you would need headless content to be "visible" in order to scrape it