# Get html of inspect element source with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm working in selenium with Chrome.
The webpage I'm accessing updates dynamically. 
I need the html that shows the results, I can access it when I do 'inspect element'.
I don't get how I need to access that html from my code. I always get the original html.

I tried this: [Get HTML Source of WebElement in Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

```
browser.get('http://bijsluiters.fagg-afmps.be/?localeValue=nl')
searchform = browser.find_element_by_class_name('iceInpTxt')
searchform.send_keys('cefuroxim')
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('iceCmdBtn').click()

element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('contentContainer')
html = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
browser.close()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's working after some delay. If I were you I should try to experiment with the delay time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('http://bijsluiters.fagg-afmps.be/?localeValue=nl')
searchform = browser.find_element_by_class_name('iceInpTxt')
searchform.send_keys('cefuroxim')
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('iceCmdBtn').click()

time.sleep(10)

element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('contentContainer')
html = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
browser.close()
print(html)
```

**Addition**: a nicer way is to let the script proceed when an element is available (because of time it takes with JS (for example) before a specific element has been added to the DOM). The element to look for in your example is table with id `iceDatTbl` (for what I could find after a quick look).

Comment: You're right, it works. Now I feel stupid, I tried this before but only with a delay of 1 second because I saw instant results when I did it manually. Thanks.