# How to keep updated page in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

When parsing, a pop-up window appears from which you need to get the data. if i use
`driver.page_source` then it doesn't grab the code from the popup.

How do I real-time copy lines of html code using selenium?

Comment: Hey, you might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python). Locating the popup and extracting its content is most likely the best way to go.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could need the method switchTo. This method helps to change to iframe. [Example](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) [Example](https://blog.testproject.io/2020/06/18/selenium-switch-methods-chapter-5/)