# Am I selecting all of these tags or just the first one by using '//'?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

Ignore the portuguese comments

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/WEB SCRAPPING/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')#padrão
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python')#pagina desejada
search_bar=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//form[@id='search']")
sleep(5)
search_bar.click()#clicar
sleep(5)
print(search_bar.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
driver.close()#sempre que abrir o chrome fechar
```

I'd like to know if this chunk below

```
"//form[@id='search']"
```

will select only the first descendant (from html) tag with id=search, and if then I switch that for "//*form[@id='search']" so would I have all of those descendants?

Comment: Did you test the code? What happened? How many & which one was selected? Is that page valid HTML (meaning only one element with a certain id)? So many questions...

Comment: I would just like to know about / and //, the html code is too big to look over

Answer (score 0):

- XPATH `//` means **look over all page body's children elements**. If you intend to look for an element within another element, you need to put a dot in front of the slashes: `.//`. A single slash, `/` means find only the immediate children of page body, or whatever parent element.
- Now, Selenium `find_element` will only look for a single element. If there are multiple elements with the same locator (eg same `class`), it will return the first match. If you intend to locate all elements with a particular locator, then use `find_elements`, and that will return a list of such elements.
- Also, in a page with valid HTML, only a single element will have a particular `id` attribute value.

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).